# Abbreviation index with nomenclature

Tags: acronyms, nomenclature

**SOLVED: I don't know why, but I throwed one abbreviation out of the document. Then I compiled and it worked. After that I copied it back again and it still worked. And since I did that I had no further problems. Strange.**

First, I have to say I'm a beginner in TeX. Im currently writing my master thesis with Texmaker and MiKTeX 2.9 (`pdftex`) under Windows 7.

I actually wrote 70 pages without any problems. In my thesis I use the `nomenclature` package for the abbreviation index.

Now, since a few days I've been getting the following error message(s):

```
! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.
```

and

```
! Extra \endgroup.
```

I get the "lonely item" message for a multiple abbreviation in the index.

I'm trying to comment out some chapters and nomenclature uses. The problem is that it is not reproducible. Sometimes I can compile the document when I comment out this chapter and the next time compiling files again and then it doesn't compile at all.

I searched Google, but there's no solution for me. I haven't multiple abbreviations in the index. I tried to compile it under Linux and with TeX  Live under Windows and Linux. Same errors.

Abbreviation index code in the main file:

```
\usepackage[intoc,german]{nomencl}
\let\abk\nomenclature
\renewcommand{\nomname}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}
\setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{.20\hsize}
\setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}
\makenomenclature
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{\markboth{\nomname}{\nomname}}
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\vspace{12pt}
}
```

and

```
\newpage
\printnomenclature
\clearpage
```

When I comment out the `\printnomenclature` command it works, but there is no index in the document.

In my chapter `.tex` files I use

```
\abk[PIN]{PIN}{Personal Identification Number}
```

I also checked the temporary file where  MakeIndex generates the abbreviation index. But there are no syntax errors. The only idea left I have that there is a problem when the abbreviation index is longer then one page.

Examples of the usage of the  `\abk`-command:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item \textbf{Linear Threshold Unit}\index{LTU}\abk[LTU]{LTU}{Linear Threshold Unit} ~\\
following text
\end{itemize}
```

or

```
Sie präsentieren die Resultate einer Analyse von GUI-based Intrusion Detection (GUIID)\abk[GUIID]{GUIID}{GUI-based Intrusion Detection} Systemen.
```

Example from the `.nls`-File (XOR is throwing an lonely item error):

```
\begin{thenomenclature}
 [...]
 \nomgroup{X}
\item [{XaaS}]\begingroup Everything as a Service\nomeqref {0}
    \nompageref{16}
\item [{XOR}]\begingroup eXclusive OR\nomeqref {0}\nompageref{43}
\end{thenomenclature}
```

After deleting all \abk from the whole document, so there are no(!) abbreviations in it, there are still two errors:

```
! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{thenomenclature}.
```

and

```
 ! Extra  \endgroup."
```

Comment: My feeling is towards a bad `\abk` command, in the sense that one of its arguments contains a "fragile" command. Can you show, adding them to your question, the `\abk` commands in the offending chapter?

Comment: I forgot! Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: The problem is there is no "one" offending chapter. Sometimes it compiles and sometimes it doesn't, when I comment a random chapter and then it doesn't compile when I comment out ALL chapters. It's just so frustrating. Thanks :)! P.S.: I checked all my \abk commands and they're all in the same way. I wrote them just after the first usage of an abbreviation in the text.

Comment: Please, add a self contained example; it needn't be long, just to give an idea of what you're doing in the document body.

Comment: I added examples in the question

Comment: The error should be accompanied by a line number. Can you add what's the contents of the `.nls` file around that line in case of errors?

Comment: Examples added. The XOR-Item is throwing an error.

Comment: Sorry, but I've tried with multiple page nomenclature list, but I got no error. You should try producing a minimal example that shows the error (I know it can be difficult) or make available the complete source.

Comment: Yeah, it was only one under 1000 solutions I found with Google which does'nt work. Actually it is possible to compile every chapter, when all others are out or one or two other chapters are outcommented. I will try to show the errors but this is actually one of my problems that I can't do it. It seems so random...

Comment: After deleting all \abk from the whole document, so there are no(!) abbreviations in it, there are still two errors:"! LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{thenomenclature}." and "! Extra \endgroup." (added to question)

Comment: No idea why, but solved.